# Supersized Slider: Title

Tags: jquery, html, title, supersized

In Supersized, how can I have a different div per slide instead of just using the 'title' query?

```
{image : 'http://buildinternet.s3.amazonaws.com/projects/supersized/3.2/slides/wojno-1.jpg', title : 'Image Credit: Colin Wojno', ...
```

Instead of just the text changing ("Image Credit..."), I want a different 'div' with different styling per slide. How can I do that?

Thanks!

Comment: You need to provide more than that. Where is the relevant code? What have you tried so far? I'm assuming Supersized is a jQuery plugin - link to it.

Comment: I am using this: http://buildinternet.com/project/supersized/
I still playing with its demo code so there isn't much progress.

Comment: Hmm. I don't completely understand what you're trying to accomplish. Do you want to add a class/id to each div so you can style them? And you say "per page" are you talking about per slide?

Comment: Yes. That was supposed to be per slide. The current code only allows me to change the text or 'title' and put it in the 'slidecaption' div. I would like to have a different div on every slide.

Comment: Make a jsfiddle and add your current code, that should help: http://jsfiddle.net/